# SharePoint Online - Restrict users to select not more than one value for a look up field

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, lookup-column

How to restrict users to select only one value in a look up column.

Scenario: I have a look up column and i want users to select only one value [image: Look up]

Example: For Opportunity ID (originally a number column for another list) is a look up column for this document library.  I have selected 4, 6 and can select more. I want to restrict users to only select one choice 4 or 6 or any other number, but just 1 value.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to list/library settings->find and click the lookup column, in the edit column page, select “yes” for Enforce unique values or unchecked the “Allow multiple values”.

[image]